# Sublime LaTeXTools warnings + not compile

Tags: compiling, sublime-text, latextools

After being working in TeXworks I decided to use Sublime+LaTeXTools. I did the setup correctly (checking system says so). Now I am trying to compile two simple documents, but sublime returns some warnings and does not compile the outputs.

Any thoughts?

### Document 1 Warning:

Basic Builder: running pdflatex...done.

No errors. Warnings:

D:.....tex: Package bibentry Warning: You have used \nobibliography*(bibentry)                without a following \bibliography.

### D:.....log:1: Double-click here to open the full log.

### Document 2 Warning

[no file]: Class scrbook Warning: Usage of package `parskip' together(scrbook)              with a KOMA-Script class is not recommended.
[no file]:91: LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape`OT1/cmr/bx/n' in size <10.5> not available(Font)              size <10.95> substituted on input line 91.
[no file]:91: LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OML/cmm/b/it' in size <10.5> not available(Font)              size <10.95> substituted on input line 91.
[no file]:91: LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape`OMS/cmsy/b/n' in size <10.5> not available(Font)              size <10.95> substituted on input line 91.
[no file]: LaTeX Font Warning: Size substitutions with differences(Font)              up to 0.45pt have occurred.

### (Log parsing issues. Disregard unless something else is wrong.)

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! It only says 1) you shouldn't use  the `parskip` package with `koma-script`. The latter has its own tools for paragraph spacing. See § 3.10, pp. 77-78 in the documentation. 2) for some reason, you want to use a 10.5pt  font size, which is not available in LaTeX,  which uses a fixed set of font sizes, so it replaces with the standard size 10.95pt.

Comment: note both those warnings come from latex so the editor you use, sublime text or texworks will make no difference you would get the same warning whatever editor you used to write the file.